# Get all bytes of stream from webcam after being compressed by codec with ffmpeg?

Tags: vb.net, vb6, ffmpeg, streaming

I need to capture every single byte of the video stream from webcam  -after using commandline-ffmpeg to compress it with codec.

So can you please light me up with somewhat the ffmpeg commandline look like and the strategy to get the output stream into my program written by VB6 or VB.net ? (I need to manipulate with every single byte!) Highly appreciate any suggestion.

---

**Update** : I wonder if it's possible to save the output as "avi" file on hard disk and at the same time use my program to read content of the saving file. Can I playback the "part of avi file" that I retrieve while the file is being saved (appended) ? Is there any better file format for writting & reading (recording & playing) at the same time other than "avi" ?

Or any better/faster solution?

Comment: Not sure entirely, but you need to use the DirectShow filter.  This is how to capture audio:  `ffmpeg -nostats -f dshow -i audio="S/PDIF (M-Audio Delta AP 192)" -acodec mp3 -f mp3 -ab`

Comment: Thanks ! I see some people use the output as url (smth like "192.168.1.123:8090"), but i want to get the stream into my program, so do you know how ?

Comment: Use STDIO.  The last parameter should be `-`.

Comment: @Brad : Can you please explain more about STDIO and the last parameter "-" ? I've just tried the last param as "-", but I've got error "[NULL @ 03714500] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'pipe:'
pipe:: Invalid argument"

Comment: There's nothing more to explain.  If you set the last parameter as `-`, FFmpeg will output to STDOUT.  Show your full command, and how you are executing it in your code.

Comment: I've tried this command in Windows Command Prompt:  "ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Lenovo EasyCamera" stdio -"

Comment: Use the command I posted in the first place.  You're not specifying any format, and why did you put `stdio` in there?  `ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Lenovo EasyCamera" -f mp4 -` or something.  You need to specify the output format at a minimum, and it's best if you set the output codecs to your specifications as well.  Also, you don't want to run that in a command prompt or the raw data will be dumped to your console.  If you do, at least use `> someFile` to output to a file.

Comment: Thanks so much ! It works! But instead of using format of "mp4" (which will cause this error "[mp4 @ 03712a00] muxer does not support non seekable output" ) I used the format "avi". The full command should look like "ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Lenovo EasyCamera" -f avi -"
@Brad : Please post your answer that I can accept as solution.

Comment: Great!  Glad to see you got it working.

Answer (score 1):

Pelase go through the page https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Webcam
It is clearly mention there how to capture webcam video using ffmpeg. 
Yes you can save avi stream to disk and read from it at the same time, I am sure it is possible in linux because there is no file locking.
Or you can write to a pipe and read it from the pipe frame by frame. 
Linux example to capture video and write it to a pipe.
Reading from /dev/video0

ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 25 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video0 -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p pipe1.

You should first create pipe1 to run this command, now you can read from this pipe. Piple is FIFO data strecture in linux which will flush as data is being read. SO this will suit your requirement.

Comment: I've solved the problem in Windows, but your answer is for sure useful for a lot of other linux-ers.

Comment: @vantrung-cuncon You can also provide an answer for Windows users (and the link Satyam provided also has Windows examples).